# crop random shaped polygon from an image and paste the cropped shape in a random place of another image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm a total beginner in python and opencv. Basically, I googled around and found 3 sets of code. Now, I'm just trying to put them together in order to achieve my target which is "crop random shaped polygon from image A and then paste the random polygonal shaped portion of image A into image B". I'm using Brezier's Curve and other methods to get a random shaped polygon with curves. After that put the values of x and y into a 2-D numpy array. Then pass the array of the coordinates(ROI/vertices) to boundingRectangnle(). If the vertices are integers, this code is working as I'm expecting. But when vertices are floating point numbers, boundingRectangnle() is throwing an error message:

---

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0)
>   /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp:743: error:
>   (-215:Assertion failed) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth ==
>   CV_32S) in function 'pointSetBoundingRect'

---

This is how I get vertices of random shaped polygon:

```
bernstein = lambda n, k, t: binom(n,k)* t**k * (1.-t)**(n-k)

def bezier(points, num=200):
    N = len(points)
    t = np.linspace(0, 1, num=num)
    curve = np.zeros((num, 2))
    for i in range(N):
        curve += np.outer(bernstein(N - 1, i, t), points[i])
    return curve

class Segment():
    def __init__(self, p1, p2, angle1, angle2, **kw):
        self.p1 = p1; self.p2 = p2
        self.angle1 = angle1; self.angle2 = angle2
        self.numpoints = kw.get("numpoints", 100)
        r = kw.get("r", 0.3)
        d = np.sqrt(np.sum((self.p2-self.p1)**2))
        self.r = r*d
        self.p = np.zeros((4,2))
        self.p[0,:] = self.p1[:]
        self.p[3,:] = self.p2[:]
        self.calc_intermediate_points(self.r)

    def calc_intermediate_points(self,r):
        self.p[1,:] = self.p1 + np.array([self.r*np.cos(self.angle1),
                                    self.r*np.sin(self.angle1)])
        self.p[2,:] = self.p2 + np.array([self.r*np.cos(self.angle2+np.pi),
                                    self.r*np.sin(self.angle2+np.pi)])
        self.curve = bezier(self.p,self.numpoints)


def get_curve(points, **kw):
    segments = []
    for i in range(len(points)-1):
        seg = Segment(points[i,:2], points[i+1,:2], points[i,2],points[i+1,2],**kw)
        segments.append(seg)
    curve = np.concatenate([s.curve for s in segments])
    return segments, curve

def ccw_sort(p):
    d = p-np.mean(p,axis=0)
    s = np.arctan2(d[:,0], d[:,1])
    return p[np.argsort(s),:]

def get_bezier_curve(a, rad=0.2, edgy=0):
    """ given an array of points *a*, create a curve through
    those points. 
    *rad* is a number between 0 and 1 to steer the distance of
          control points.
    *edgy* is a parameter which controls how "edgy" the curve is,
           edgy=0 is smoothest."""
    p = np.arctan(edgy)/np.pi+.5
    a = ccw_sort(a)
    a = np.append(a, np.atleast_2d(a[0,:]), axis=0)
    d = np.diff(a, axis=0)
    ang = np.arctan2(d[:,1],d[:,0])
    f = lambda ang : (ang>=0)*ang + (ang<0)*(ang+2*np.pi)
    ang = f(ang)
    ang1 = ang
    ang2 = np.roll(ang,1)
    ang = p*ang1 + (1-p)*ang2 + (np.abs(ang2-ang1) > np.pi )*np.pi
    ang = np.append(ang, [ang[0]])
    a = np.append(a, np.atleast_2d(ang).T, axis=1)
    s, c = get_curve(a, r=rad, method="var")
    x,y = c.T
    return x,y, a


def get_random_points(n, scale=0.8, mindst=None, rec=0):
    """ create n random points in the unit square, which are *mindst*
    apart, then scale them."""
    mindst = mindst or 1.0/n
    a = np.random.rand(n,2)
    d = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.diff(ccw_sort(a), axis=0), axis=1)**2)
    if np.all(d >= mindst) or rec>=200:
        return a*scale
    else:
        return get_random_points(n=n, scale=scale, mindst=mindst, rec=rec+1)

figure, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect("equal")

rad = 0.2
edgy = 0.05
#for c in np.array([[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]]):
for c in np.array([[0,0]]):
    a = get_random_points(n=2, scale=1) + c
    x,y, _ = get_bezier_curve(a,rad=rad, edgy=edgy)

print x
print ("\n\n")
print y
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

This is the code to draw random shaped polygon from image A:

```
img = cv2.imread('cat.jpg',0)

#pts = np.array([[120,456], [456,678], [875,345], [980,234], [943,123], [45,786], [126,50]])
pts = np.array([[0.14837693,0.03585092],
                [0.14529922,0.03757408],
                [0.14255947,0.03953773],
                [0.14015068,0.04173684],
                [0.14837693,0.03585092]])

pts = np.array(pts).astype(np.int64)
print (pts.ndim)
print (pts.shape)
print (pts.size)
print (pts.dtype)
## (1) Crop the bounding rect
rect = cv2.boundingRect(pts)

x,y,w,h = rect
croped = img[y:y+h, x:x+w].copy()

## (2) make mask
pts = pts - pts.min(axis=0)

mask = np.zeros(croped.shape[:2], np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [pts], -1, (255, 255, 255), -1, cv2.LINE_AA)


## (3) do bit-op
dst = cv2.bitwise_and(croped, croped, mask=mask)

## (4) add the white background
bg = np.ones_like(croped, np.uint8)*255
cv2.bitwise_not(bg,bg, mask=mask)
dst2 = bg+ dst


cv2.imwrite("croped.png", croped)
cv2.imwrite("mask.png", mask)
cv2.imwrite("dst.png", dst)
cv2.imwrite("dst2.png", dst2)
```

First portion of the code works without any problem. The second part (cropping picture) also works fine when a numpy array of integers are provided to 'boundingRectangle()

```
pts = np.array([[120,456], [456,678], [875,345], [980,234], [943,123], [45,786], [126,50]])
```

But meet this error

---

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0)
>   /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp:743: error:
>   (-215:Assertion failed) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth ==
>   CV_32S) in function 'pointSetBoundingRect'

---

when the array elements are floating point numbers.

```
pts = np.array([[0.14837693,0.03585092],
                [0.14529922,0.03757408],
                [0.14255947,0.03953773],
                [0.14015068,0.04173684],
                [0.14837693,0.03585092]])
```

How do get to get over this problem? I'm not obliged to follow this method to get it done. So, new techniques and suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.